# How to enable both side lighting for GL_POINTS with vertex normals

Tags: c++, c, opengl, legacy

How to enable both side lighting for `GL_POINTS` in opengl?
It seems `glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);` is working for only facets, but not `GL_POINTS`.

What I am doing is supplying both `vertices` and the `vertex normals` with lighting enabled. With `GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE` disabled, GL_POINTS are lit according to the normal direction. But I cannot enable both sided lighting for `GL_POINTS`.

Can this be done using `OpenGL` legacy functions? Or would I have to render both sides by negating all the normals?

Thanks in advance. Please do not comment to use `modern OpenGL` as that is not the answer to my question, but only a suggestion.

Comment: OpenGL is a **C** API. What is the point in putting a "C++" title and tag here?

Comment: @Luca: That is okay. But then how to render both direction of the normals. A practical example is when rendering is done only with dense set of vertices. And the normals are un-oriented. The importance of my humble query is not in the meaning of the English terms that I have used.

Comment: @user3078414: he he! I thought of adding Python also :) (punintended). Please check wikipedia. `Open Graphics Library (OpenGL) is a cross-language, cross-platform application programming interface (API) for rendering 2D and 3D vector graphics. `

Comment: How about adding a second light source that lights the scene from the opposite direction?

Answer (score 2):

> How to enable both side lighting for GL_POINTS in opengl?

You don't. Points and lines do not *have* sides. Only face primitives (triangles, quads, etc) have sides.

So if you want the lighting computation to reverse the normal if the normal is facing away or something, then yes, you will have to render your geometry twice.

Comment: Thanks! Now, that is what I am doing drawing two point clouds. `P1 = {v_i, n_i}` and `P2 = {v_i-w*n_i, -n_i}` for small `w` so that the same points do not alias.
But even then, I am unable to view the back side lit.

Comment: Thanks again! I was doing a silly mistake of not setting `P1->num_vertices` during its initialization. It's working.

Comment: if i have to render my geometry twice than for the back lit faces i have to inverse the normals , Di i also have to change the winding order ?

Comment: @Summit: This question is about lighting on *points*. Triangles actually have sides, so you can implement two-sided lighting yourself.